# Choose usage is correct?

Tags: present-tense

Using "choose" as present tense is correct at below? I am not native English speaker, when I thought my language, logically I would use "and parents could choose school offering .... "

"In ancient Greece, anyone could open a school and decide which subject to teach, and parents choose school offering affordable monthly fees and the subjects they wanted their children to learn."

Comment: "Choose" works. You should add a determiner before *school*, though (... *choose [a/the/any/...] school* ...).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Lawrence.  "Choose" is correct in this case, but it's clearer if you say "... and parents choose the school offering …

Or, it could also be further clarified: "... and parents choose the school which offers affordable monthly fees and subjects they want their children to learn."  I changed "wanted" to "want" to match the tense of the verb "choose."